# What is the explanation for the following strange behavior of the forecast from ETS(M,A,M)?

Tags: r, time-series, forecast

I have the following time series data

```
myts <- ts(c(0.00000000000000000, 0.00000000000000000, 0.00000000000000000, 0.00000000000000000, 0.00000000000000000, 0.00000000000000000, 0.00000000000000000, 0.00000000000000000, 0.00000000000000000, 0.00000000000000000, 0.00000000000000000, 0.00000000000000000, 8238.8611111111095, 9034.7311827956983, 12636.097222222223, 12662.163978494624, 16275.860215053764, 14484.416666666666, 11582.013422818791, 15241.791666666666, 12343.279569892473, 10611.491935483875, 9028.3184523809541, 9163.8088829071348, 8106.0416666666679, 12048.924731182793, 12787.166666666666, 12948.669354838710, 14678.494623655914, 14843.333333333334, 15334.899328859061, 16519.291666666668, 11172.728494623658, 9201.5322580645152, 7122.7442528735646, 7560.3633916554509, 9679.5972222222226, 9998.2526881720441, 10896.263888888889, 12919.233870967742, 14972.849462365592, 25215.416666666668, 14731.302013422815, 15287.416666666668, 12618.010752688171, 10917.620967741936, 8126.1383928571413, 7393.3378196500689, 8655.5694444444434, 10831.276881720431, 12685.777777777776, 12266.747311827956, 12622.916666666664, 14832.180555555553, 14781.275167785234, 14516.861111111111, 13250.873655913978, 12137.231182795698, 11009.747023809525, 7856.5952301480502),
           frequency = 12, start = c(2000, 4))
```

which is a monthly time series data where the first year comprises of only zeroes. If we use `forecast` package's `ets()` with ETS(M,A,M) as our model of choice, it will rightly complain that we have wrongly-chosen ETS(M,A,M), which is inappropriate for time series that contain zeroes. 
I then did a simple experiment whereby I perform translation on the time series values, just to avoid the zeroes in the beginning.

```
> trans <- 1
> myts_trans <- ts(as.numeric(myts) + trans, frequency = frequency(myts), start = start(myts))
> autoplot(myts_trans, series = "DATA") + autolayer(forecast(ets(myts_trans, model = "MAM", damped = FALSE)), PI=FALSE, series="FCT)
```

With this, I get a forecast that looks quite reasonable, except for the fact that I think it has a trend that is a bit too strong (besides the *outlier* element in the 4th year, the time series seems to show a seasonality pattern with no trend).

But then, when I started to play around with other translation amount, I started  to get very weird forecast values. For e.g., with `trans <- 1000`, I get the following (unexpectedly-high) forecast results:

[forecast from ETS(M,A,M) with translation = 1000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmUSl.png)

If you further play around with the translation value, you'd see that we can get wildly different forecast values using the same ETS(M,A,M) method. For e.g., with translation = 2000, you get similarly very-high forecast values as translation = 1000 (but the exact numbers differ), but if you set translation = 10000, you will get again a reasonable forecast, just like the case when you use translation = 1.

Worth noting that when I used the `smooth` package (with the `es()` function), I get more-or-less similarly strange forecasts using certain translation values (though the exact values differ significantly) compared to `ets()`.

My questions:

1. What could be the explanation that caused such a strange result of ETS(M,A,M). Is it due to the *flat* first year? Consequently: Are multiplicative seasonality/errors ETS not suitable then for these kinds of time series data?
2. Shouldn't it be expected that performing translation on a time series would not change the *shape* of the forecast values when using a certain method (i.e., I would expect that the forecast values would be equal to the forecast values of the untranslated data + some fixed amount)?

Answer (score 0):

You are fitting a multiplicative model, so shifting the data up by a fixed amount will change things a lot. The flat first year is not the issue. The issue is that seasonality is assumed to be multiplicative, but you are thinking of it as additive.

Imagine your data is generated using a linear trend and a set of multiplicative seasonal indices: $y_t = (a+bt)*s_t*n_t$ where $n_t$ is a multiplicative noise term. Then adding a constant to $y_t$ does not translate into a simple change to the trend or seasonality. So the model tries to approximate as best it can using the data provided.

On the other hand, if your model is additive, it is of the form $y_t = a + bt + s_t + n_t$. Then adding a constaint to $y_t$ simply changes the value of $a$.

Comment: Thanks Prof. Hyndman for the answer. It's a privilege to get an answer directly from you. I understand now the issue with the shifting/translation in connection with multiplicative error models. For my first question, can I assume then, that not all data can be fitted nicely with multiplicative error/seasonality models, and that we should be careful when using them? (Or alternatively, just let the automatic forecasting figure out which model is best for my data?)